# Should I repost comment as answer or edit an existing answer?

Tags: discussion

I don't currently have enough on-site reputation to post a new answer to [permission error when installing ttf-mscorefonts-installer](https://askubuntu.com/q/771936/269638), but due to the up-votes on my comment under https://askubuntu.com/a/812152/269638, I presume that my comment has helped a few users with this (or related) error.

Shall I edit the answer I commented under? Can my account be unlocked to make a new answer (as I'm under the au.se reputation limit that excludes the association bonus)? Is there a way to answer in the form of a "community wiki"? Or should I just leave it as a comment?

Comment: I am not sure whether it should be an answer (you'd definitely have to expand it then and describe what you are doing and why in more detail), but I unprotected the question anyway. If you decide you want to post it as answer, you can do that from now on.

Comment: And no, I would not consider editing the answer to be a good option. What you are suggesting in the comment is quite different from the answer's content and would probably be rejected. Edits should only improve existing content or add at most very related updates, but not add completely new ideas.

Comment: thanks.  feel free to edit my answer and/or re-lock the question.

Comment: Looks good, gave you an upvote :)

Comment: I have no idea why that question was protected in the first place. There's only one deleted answer and there seems to be absolutely no reason to protect. Somebody was being over-zealous. Thanks for unprotecting @ByteCommander.

Comment: @terdon It was only fair, because that overzealous person who protected the question in the first place was me... I can only bring up that this happened back when I was new to the protection privilege as an excuse.